# Give the different row value when text string found in another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Having issues with merging some IFs and VLOOKUPs most probably.
Basically, workflow would look like below and I don't quite know how to type it into one formula.

1. Look for value from **Values to look for** in the table on the right hand side.
2. If found in the **list** text string, return the corresponding value from **add/remove** column to B column.

[Excel screenshot sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNqKa.png)

Comment: Please give examples of what you have tried, show the formulas you are using and how you want to combine them. I am sure we can help, but we need to see the effort you have put in and where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will only work if you make the name for the values unique. What I mean by this is, that you will need to change the name of value1 to value01 if you have more than 10 values. If you have more than 100 values, than you will need to change the name to value001 and so on.

Then use this in `B2` and drag down as needed:

```
{=INDEX($D$3:$D$6,MATCH(TRUE,FIND(A2,$E$3:$E$6)>0,0))}
```

NOTE: you dont have to entere the brackets `{}`. These just indicate that this is an array-formula. This needs to be entered with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER instead of the normal ENTER.

Comment: This would not work always correctly as Value1 and Value11 are the same for FIND.

Comment: That is True, but then he just needs to make the values unique. Use Value01 instead of Value1 if you have more than 10 values. Value001 instead of Value1 if you have more than 100 values and so on.

Comment: Indeed. Would advise to put that into answer. Would be great if you could additionaly add some information about the logic of the formula for other users.

Answer (score 0):

try this formula: =IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(A2,E2),"Not Found")="Not Found","Not Found",D2)

also please see the screenshot attached [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKf69.png)